# models.FileField.read csv returns b'0,0,0,0\n1,1,1,1'

Tags: python, django, csv

I read the file by 
`models.FileField` and it returns

`myModel.document` is `models.FileField` object.

```
f = myModel.document.read()
print(f)
```

this might be csv file, but how can I handle this object?????

`b'0,0,0,0\n1,1,1,1'`

Comment: What do you mean by "handle"? `.read()` returns the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to take that bytes data and insert into a CSV, you can do the following:

```
import csv

data = b'0,0,0,0\n1,1,1,1'

with open("data.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    for line in data.splitlines():
        writer.writerow(line.split(','))
```

If you want to read that data, you can do:

```
data = b'0,0,0,0\n1,1,1,1'
print(data.decode())
```

Output:

```
0,0,0,0
1,1,1,1
```

Comment: Thank you to your help. I noticed this is byte code.